# Dropzone shows upload success but file is not uploaded in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm still learning Laravel and trying to build some sort of an article management system. As part of form for inserting new articles I want to also upload multiple pictures of them. The upload shows success, yet there is no file in uploads folder. Here is my form code:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin_artikli.store', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'create_artikal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Firma', 'Firma') !!}
        {!! Form::text('firma_id', Input::old('firma_id'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Naziv', 'Naziv') !!}
        {!! Form::text('naziv', Input::old('naziv'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Opis', 'Opis') !!}
        {!! Form::text('opis', Input::old('opis'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Cijena', 'Cijena') !!}
        {!! Form::text('cijena', Input::old('cijena'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('kolicina', 'kolicina') !!}
        {!! Form::text('kolicina', Input::old('kolicina'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('dostupnost', 'dostupnost') !!}
        {!! Form::text('dostupnost', Input::old('dostupnost'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::select('aktivan', array('D' => 'Aktivan', 'N' => 'Neaktivan'), 'D')  !!}
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::select('aktivan', array('D' => 'Aktivan', 'N' => 'Neaktivan'), 'D')  !!}
    </div>  

    {!! Form::submit('Kreiraj artikal', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'create_artikal_submit')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My routes.php(showing only relevant):

```
Route::post('/upload', 'ArtikalAdminController@upload');
Route::resource('admin_artikli', 'ArtikalAdminController');
```

My controller methods for store and upload:

```
public function upload(){
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'image|max:3000'
    );
    echo "eldaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar";
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
    }
    $file = Input::file('file');
    $extension = File::extension($file['name']);
    $directory = public_path().'uploads/'.sha1(time());
    $filename = sha1(time().time()).".{$extension}";
    $file->move($directory, $filename);
    $upload_success = Input::file('file', $directory, $filename)->move($directory, $filename);;
    echo $directory;
    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}



 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $artikal = new Artikal;
    $artikal->firma_id       = Input::get('firma_id');
    $artikal->naziv          = Input::get('naziv');
    $artikal->sifra          = Input::get('sifra');
    $artikal->opis           = Input::get('opis');
    $artikal->cijena         = Input::get('cijena');
    $artikal->kolicina       = Input::get('kolicina');
    $artikal->dostupnost     = Input::get('dostupnost');
    $artikal->aktivan        = Input::get('aktivan');
    $artikal->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Uspješno unesen artikal!');

    //return redirect()->back();

}
```

Finally, dropzone options I am currently using:

```
  Dropzone.options.createArtikal = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  maxFiles: 10,

  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;

    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    var element = document.getElementById('create_artikal_submit');
    var form = document.getElementById('create_artikal');
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
      // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
      // Hide the success button or the complete form.
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
      // Redirect user or notify of success.
      form.submit();
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
      // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error

    });
  }

}
```

I know this is lacking many things, but I'm trying to go on step at a time and I'm stuck here. When I check the network tab of dev tools I see XHR requests are 200 OK, but yet I see no file.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write **'files' => true** in form, update form & try.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin_artikli.store', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'create_artikal', 'files'=>true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
```